# Where clause is not working for all columns in MySQL Select-Query

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I hava a query for extracting entries of a MySQL table, depending on a search input done by the user which are then presented.

```
$abfrage = "SELECT id, motivname, preis, masse, produktart, neu, angebot FROM $db.artikel
 INNER JOIN $db.formate ON $db.artikel.format=$db.formate.format
 WHERE (UPPER(motivname) LIKE UPPER('%{$keywordAct}%')
 OR id LIKE '%{$keywordAct}%'
 OR UPPER(produktart) LIKE UPPER('%{$keywordAct}%'))
 AND $db.artikel.aktiv=1
 ORDER BY id";
```

The query works perfectly, except that the expression aktiv=1 is omitted. Results will also be displayed where aktiv is set to 0. "aktiv" is an int-column within the table "artikel" (See below).

However the query works fine if I switch the last clause

```
AND $db.artikel.aktiv=1
```

to e.g.

```
AND $db.artikel.neu=1
```

Articles where neu=0 are not displayed, which is also an int-column.

So I think there is a problem within the table setup in MySQL but cannot figure it out. There is one other column "aktiv" in another table of the same database but this table is not addressed by this query and I also specify the aktiv column of the artikel-table.

The table setup looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `artikel` (
 `id` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `motivnummer` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `motivname` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
 `format` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `preis` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `anzahl_lager` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `anzahl_verkauft` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `anzahl_kostenlos` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `aktiv` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `neu` int(1) NOT NULL,
 `angebot` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

I am happy for some input how to make the query works as it is suppposed to be. Thank you in advance.

PS: In terms of security reasons, the keywords are already escaped in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have added `OR` clause.

So, even if `artikel.aktiv` is 0 and other condition is true, it will return rows with `aktiv` 0.

**Solution:**

And proper curly braces.

```
$abfrage = "SELECT id, motivname, preis, masse, produktart, neu, angebot FROM $db.artikel
 INNER JOIN $db.formate ON $db.artikel.format=$db.formate.format
 WHERE ((UPPER(motivname) LIKE UPPER('%{$keywordAct}%')
 OR id LIKE '%{$keywordAct}%'
 OR UPPER(produktart) LIKE UPPER('%{$keywordAct}%')))
 AND ($db.artikel.aktiv=1)
 ORDER BY id";
```

Your all conditions were going in `OR`.

`AND` condition will work only if you separate it from `OR`.

Comment: I already put the OR clauses from the AND clause with braces.

And again, the query works for other columns in the AND-clause fine, where it filters only true values.

I tried your code and it is also not working for the AND-clause.